# overflow: auto - no right padding & margin, chrome

Tags: overflow, padding, margin

The problem is that there is no right padding in the parent div and no right margin in the child div. I  am using chrome.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Template</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style = "padding: 50px; overflow: auto; width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: red;">
        <div style = "width: 500px; height: 500px; background-color: green;"></div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div style = "overflow: auto; width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: red;">
        <div style = "margin: 50px; width: 500px; height: 500px; background-color: green;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for padding, unfortunately it does not work with margin:

```css
.container {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}
.padding {
  float: left;
  padding: 50px;
}
.content {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="padding">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```